# Do a split on Carriage return and create an array in ksh

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, ksh

I would like to do a split based on Carriage return and subsequently create an array.

**process.txt**

```
siebmtshm 30933160 /app/cis/u01/sia80/siebsrvr/temp/SIEBEL_30933160   
siebmtshm 31064248 /app/cis/u01/sia80/siebsrvr/temp/SIEBEL_28508402
```

**Output of the array should be:**

```
Array[0] = siebmtshm 30933160 /app/cis/u01/sia80/siebsrvr/temp/SIEBEL_30933160   
Array[1] = siebmtshm 31064248 /app/cis/u01/sia80/siebsrvr/temp/SIEBEL_28508402
```

Comment: "Quick reply on this is very much appreciated.". This forum is for programming questions. It is not for freebie consulting. Show us the code you have tried. Then maybe we can help. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple as your process.txt file is already, technically, split.

You would just have to read the file, line by line, like this:

```
let tempInt=0
while read file
do
  Array[$tempInt]=$file
  let tempInt=$tempInt+1
done<process.txt
```

Added a counter in there to keep track of your index within the array.  I've done this MANY times in production jobs with no fail.  Mind you, just make sure you're using BASH as your interpreter.  You wouldn't want to be stuck in the 4096 byte limit the older KSH has.